# Schedulers.io() on parallel database search

Tags: rx-java

I wonder whether I should use Schedulers.io() or Schedulers.newThread() when I access to database tables in parallel.

For example, if I use Schedulers.io() to select the records from thousands of tables in parallel, a lot of threads newly created were in the thread pool after the task.

```
Observabe.just("table1", "table2", "table3"...)
    .flatMap(t -> {
        // creating the observable that emits the record
        return Observable create(s -> {
                   Record rec = selectFrom(t);
                   s.onNext(rec);
                   s.onCompleted();
                 })
                 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()); // select in parallel
    })...
```

However, if such task were a nightly batch, those threads do not have to be in the thread pool since most of them were not needed in most of the time.

In this case, I think that I should use Schedulers.newThread(). Is it right?

Comment: Sounds right to me. `Schedulers.io()` is an unbounded thread pool, which means that if you run a lot at once, you're going to add a lot of threads to the pool. If that is not what you want, you can use `.newThread()` to throw away each thread after you use it. You should probably restate your question as a question and then move the answer part to an answer and accept it.

Comment: I still wonder if this would be better. If I use `Schedulers.io()` and call `Schedulers.shutdown()`, does shutdown method clean the cached threads? Or does it cause other problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to limit io work in parallel then use a custom `Scheduler`:

`Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6));`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It might be the good choice when the thread lives shortly since it could be reuse in a short time. However, if I need thousands of threads, it has the same problem that the unused threads remain.