# Can Schedulers.io() be used to make asynchronous DB calls?

Tags: java, asynchronous, rx-java, rx-java2

Can Schedulers.io() be used to make asynchronous DB calls? Will it block my main thread?

Comment: also this may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284285/schedulers-io-on-parallel-database-search

Comment: You need to show the research you've done to try to answer this question yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be used, and no, it won't block your main thread. Its aim is exactly that, performing blocking IO aynchronously, such as a DB call.

The only scenario in which `io` blocks the main thread would be all the threads of the pool being occupied; That shouldn't happen with the default Scheduler, but if you want to control how many threads are launched at max, you could set your **custom** `Scheduler` with a limited size in order to avoid thread party in your ram:

```
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3));
```

Judge which approach is best for you. The first one makes thing simpler and should never block the main thread. The contra is the attack of the clones from the default Scheduler. The second one, if well configured, would be the optimal option.

And some way to use it:

```
Observable.just("yourDbTable")
         .flatMap(t->{ Record rec = selectFrom(t); .... })
         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

> [**`Schedulers.io()`**](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.html#io--)
>
> ***Creates and returns a Scheduler intended for IO-bound work***. The
> implementation is backed by an Executor thread-pool that will grow as
> needed. This **can be used for asynchronously performing blocking IO**.
>
> The implementation is **backed by a pool of single-threaded
> ScheduledExecutorService instances** that will try to reuse previously
> started instances used by the worker returned by
> Scheduler.createWorker() but **otherwise will start a new backing ScheduledExecutorService instance**.
>
> **Note that this scheduler may create
> an unbounded number of worker threads** that can result in system
> slowdowns or OutOfMemoryError. Therefore, for casual uses or when
> implementing an operator, **the Worker instances must be disposed via
> Disposable.dispose().**

Docs also suggest to **avoid computational work** on it.

Comment: Thank you. I am using vertx.webclient to perform async http requests. When I subscribe that single to an IO scheduler, the following transformations seem to not occur. Here is my next question. Do I need to use Rx with Vertx? Since Vertx is already non blocking, will Rx really help me here?

Comment: I think it helps with the paralellization of it, while rx helps with the asynchrnonous behaviour. I guess that's the point of each one, but I may be incorrect here....If my guess is correct, you'd achieve both : asynch behaviour + paralellization of the asynch process

Comment: Also rx provides mechanisms within the asynch process, such as Observable.